# Rails 3 - Queries with sub models and count statements

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to figure out a way to eliminate a bunch of queries that seem unnecessary.  Here is the situation.

model Post has_many Comments

SQL (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "comments" WHERE ("comments".post_id = 5)
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "comments" WHERE ("comments".post_id = 5)
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "comments" WHERE ("comments".post_id = 5)
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "comments" WHERE ("comments".post_id = 5)

So i'm not sure why these are running but in my view I'm checking to see if there are comments for each of the posts

```
<% if post.comments.count > 0 %> <!-- tried count, size, blank? -->
    <table class="list">
    <% post.comments.each do |animal| %>
        <tr><!-- stuff here --></tr>
    <% end %>
    </table>
<% else %>
    <h3>No comments</h3>
<% end %>
```

If there is a better way to do this check i'm all for change.  I looked at counter_cache but looks like it is only for belongs_to relationships and also I'm using subdomains so not sure counter_cache would work for me or not.

Any suggestions welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are probably not [eagerly loading comments](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) for each post.  Wherever you are setting the post variable in your controller, you probably have something like this:

```
post = Post.find(params[:id])
```

Try changing it to this:

```
post = Post.includes(:comments).find(params[:id])
```

Includes will automatically change your Post load query to join on comments and prepopulate `post.comments` with the array of all that post's comments.  Then when you do `post.comments.size` you will be asking for the length of the array (instead of asking activerecord to count how many there are).

Comment: I'm running my query as such... @posts = @current_account.posts.all(:include => [:comments]).all, but not sure this is the best way to do it. (especially for Rails 3.1

Answer (score 0):

Ummm... #includes is a class method, you can't call it on the instance returned by `Post.find(params[:id])` It's correct in principle, though, the syntax is `Post.includes(:comments).find(params[:id])`

In response to your comment:

OK, #includes is a class method for ActiveRecord::Base and its children (your models), but an instance method for ActiveRelation.

```
@posts = @current_user.posts.all(:include => [:comments]).all
```

is definitely deprecated... you want to do the inclusion before you call #all b/c in Rails 3, `@current_user.posts` will return an ActiveRelation object, whereas @current_user.posts.all is going to actually load the collection of Post objects. So I would change it to:

```
@posts = @current_user.posts.includes(:comments).all
```

You shouldn't even really need to call #all, to be honest, but see which works better for you.

Comment: I'm running my query as such... @posts = @current_account.posts.all(:include => [:comments]).all, but not sure this is the best way to do it. (especially for Rails 3.1

Comment: Edited answer in response to your comment. See if that helps.